# Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again: Java 17.0.5

Tags: java, nextflow

I am trying to use Nextflow to run a pipeline for RNA sequence; however I keep having issues with Java.

Currently the error I am receiving is:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/jgit/api/errors/GitAPIException has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:757)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:650)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:632)
```

I have the following Java Versions, but I will be honest, I tried many many routes to get to this newest version of java (the old one was:
openjdk version "1.8.0_332"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.62.0.19-CA-linux64) (build 1.8.0_332-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.62.0.19-CA-linux64) (build 25.332-b09, mixed mode))

Now these are the updated versions:
$ javac -version
javac 17.0.5

$ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.5+8 (build 17.0.5+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.5+8 (build 17.0.5+8, mixed mode, sharing)

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

A good idea in this situation would be to uninstall and install a newer version of JDK.

Answer (score 0):

You may have missed the note that usually accompanies the error above:

```
$ nextflow -h
NOTE: Nextflow is not tested with Java 1.8.0_332 -- It's recommended the use of version 11 up to 18
```

Just make sure you have [Java 11 (or later, up to 18)](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/) installed.